# mysql find the customers for the following case

Tags: mysql, filter

I have a table as like bellow:

[image]

I need to customers for the following conditions.

a. Who placed order and paid all off them. ie, customer_id: 34, 42, 70

b. Who placed order but not paid any of them. ie, customer_id: 57, 80

c. Who placed order but not paid some of them. ie, customer_id: 45, 62, 65

Note: invoice_no: 0 means order is not paid.

Need suggestions from experts. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this

**Case A**

```
   SELECT  customers.* FROM customers  INNER JOIN (  SELECT customer_id , MIN(invoice_no) minInvoice ,MAX(invoice_no) maxinvoice FROM customers  GROUP BY  customer_id ) c
     ON c.customer_id  = customers.customer_id AND c.minInvoice > 0
```

**Case B**

```
SELECT customers .* FROM  customers  INNER JOIN (  SELECT customer_id , MIN(invoice_no) minInvoice ,MAX(invoice_no) maxinvoice FROM  customers  GROUP BY  customer_id) c
    ON c.customer_id  = customers.customer_id AND c.minInvoice = 0 AND c.maxinvoice = 0;
```

**Case C**

```
  SELECT  customers.* FROM customers  INNER JOIN (  SELECT customer_id , MIN(invoice_no) minInvoice ,MAX(invoice_no) maxinvoice FROM customers  GROUP BY  customer_id ) c
     ON c.customer_id  = customers .customer_id AND c.maxinvoice > 0 AND c.mininvoice=0
```

Comment: It helps but hues loading time from my 100K records. any idea using procedure or function and can run any time. just call a function or view to get the latest records. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Case A**

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customers 
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MIN(invoice_no) > 0
```

**Case B**

```
SELECT customer_id 
FROM customers 
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MAX(invoice_no) = 0
```

**Case C**

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers 
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING MIN(invoice_no) = 0 AND MAX(invoice_no) > 0
```